# How to select the same value only once in MysQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have this table:

```
-------
id a b
-------
1  1 1
2  1 5
3  1 1
4  1 1
5  1 6
```

How do I select this?

```
-------
id a b
-------
1  1 1
2  1 5
5  1 6
```

Comment: you might want to add whether this is the final table, or whether the contents could change, in which case you'll need to describe 'what' (rows with distinct b and min id, rows with id 1,2,5 etc.) you are trying to get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, a, b from table 
where id in (1,2,5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
SELECT MIN(id), a, b FROM table GROUP BY a, b
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT MIN(id), a, b
FROM table
GROUP BY a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(id), a,b from foo group by a,b;
```

Answer (score 1):

THe below would get you what you want in your example but i am not sure if the min ID is useful if it is the key.

```
SELECT MIN(id), a, b
FROM table
GROUP BY a,b
```